# Term for when someone interferes with another's authority?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

For example, Bob is not very high ranking in the company, but he is the safety manager.  Bob tells Rich not to do something because it is not safe.  Jim is Rich's boss and tells him to ignore Bob.  Jim  ______ Bob.  Word or phrase would be great.

Edit:
For clarity, I'm looking for a word that what Jim was wrong, or at least not cool, for doing what he did.

Perhaps a better example would be one parent tells a kid to do something and the other parent tells the kid they don't have to do it.

Comment: "**Countermanded**"? Merriam-Webster defines _countermand_ as "**1:** to to revoke (a command) by a contrary order **2:** to recall or order back by a by a superseding contrary order."

Answer (score 3):

Jim ***overrules*** Bob.

[Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/overrule) says: "To reject or disallow by using one's superior authority."

Comment: I'm looking for something that has the connotation that Jim was wrong to do so. I will edit the question to clarify.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you mean :

## "Jim ***overrode*** Bob's recommandations/instructions."

[Merriam-Webster : Override](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/override)

- to make (something) no longer valid
- to have more importance or influence than (something)
- to stop an action that is done automatically by using a special command

---

I know you are looking for a word that implies that interference isn't legitimate, but if you can't find any, I would suggest using an adverb such as "wrongfully".

Comment: What about undermine?

Comment: @kevin: **undermine** captures a part of it—that Jim's interference detracts from Bob's authority.  That in itself is uncool. But if Jim did it intentionally, perhaps out of some dislike for Bob, you might say he was trying to **thwart** Bob in his exercise of authority. That is even worse.  If Jim continually meddles like this, he is trying to **usurp** Bob's authority, which is evil—a form of **backstabbing**

Answer (score 1):

I think  ***[meddle](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/meddle)*** carries the negative connotation you are looking for:

> - (usually foll by with) to interfere officiously or annoyingly
> - to involve oneself in a matter without right or invitation; interfere.

The Feee Dictionary

Answer (score 0):

Jim subverted Bob.

Subvert : undermine the power or authority of (an established system or institution)

Answer (score 0):

Jim **sabotaged** Bob's authority.

I haven't found a dictionary definition that makes this usage clear.  But here's a nice example:

> One of the worst things that you can do to your au pair is to sabotage her authority with your kids.  (http://aupairmom.com/sabotage-your-au-pairs-authority-3-easy-ways/2009/03/08/celiaharquail/)